# A generalized version of Hölder's inequality

Tags: solution-verification, banach-spaces, holder-inequality, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I've found this version from this Wikipedia [page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#/Vector-valued_functions). I've re-written the proof to make my understanding clear. Could you confirm if my attempt is correct?

---

Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $(E, \| \cdot \|)$ a Banach space.
- $\|\cdot \|_p$ the $L_p$-norm of $L_p(X, \mu,E)$.
- $f_1, \ldots, f_n, g_1, \ldots, g_n: X \to E$ are $\mu$-measurable.
- $p,q >0$ such that $1/p+1/q = 1$.

Then $$ \int_{X} \sum_{k=1}^n \| f_k (x)\| \cdot \|g_k (x) \| \mathrm d \mu (x)\leq  \left ( \sum_{k=1}^n \| f_k \|^p_p \right )^{1/p} \left (\sum_{k=1}^n  \| g_k \|_q^q \right )^{1/q}.$$

---

**My proof:** Let's first consider the case where $n=1$, i.e., $$\int_{X} {\| f (x)\|} \cdot {\|g (x)\|}{} \mathrm d \mu (x) \leq \|f\|_p \cdot  \|g\|_q.$$ WLOG, we assume $0< \| f \|_p, \| g \|_q < \infty$. Then the above inequality is equivalent to $$\int_{X}  \frac{\| f (x)\|}{\|f\|_p} \frac{\|g (x)\|}{\|g\|_q} \mathrm d \mu (x) \leq 1.$$

By Young's inequality, \begin{align}
\int_{X}  \frac{\| f (x)\|}{\|f\|_p} \frac{\|g (x)\|}{\|g\|_q} \mathrm d \mu (x) &\le \int_{X}  \frac{\| f (x)\|^p}{p\|f\|_p^p} \mathrm d \mu (x) + \int_X\frac{\|g (x)\|^q}{q\|g\|^q_q} \mathrm d \mu (x)\\
&=\frac{1}{p\|f\|_p^p} \int_{X}   \| f (x)\|^p \mathrm d \mu (x) + \frac{1}{q\|g\|^q_q} \int_X \|g (x)\|^q \mathrm d \mu (x)\\
&= \frac{1}{p\|f\|_p^p} \|f\|_p^p + \frac{1}{q\|g\|_q^q} \|g\|_q^q = \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1.
\end{align}

This completes the proof for $n = 1$. Let $[n] \triangleq \{1, \ldots, n\}$ and $([n], \mathcal P([n]), \nu)$ be the finite counting measure space. Then the product measure space $(X \times [n], \mathcal A \otimes \mathcal P([n]), \mu \otimes \nu)$ is also $\sigma$-finite. To simplify notation, let's $\lambda \triangleq \mu \otimes \nu$. Certainly, we can apply the result from the case $n=1$ to this particular product measure space. We define $f,g: X \times [n] \to E$ by $f(x,k) \triangleq f_k(x)$ and $g(x,k) \triangleq g_k(x)$. Clearly, $f$ and $g$ are measurable. It follows that \begin{align}&\int_{X \times [n]} {\| f (x,k)\|} \cdot {\|g (x,k)\|}{} \mathrm d \lambda (x,k) \\
\leq &\left (\int_{X \times [n]}\|f(x,k)\|^p \mathrm d \lambda(x,k) \right )^{1/p} \cdot   \left (\int_{X \times [n]}\|g(x,k)\|^q \mathrm d \lambda(x,k) \right )^{1/q}.\end{align}

Notice that all integrands are non-negative and measurable. So by Tonelli's theorem, we obtain \begin{align}&\int_{X} \int_{[n]} {\| f (x,k)\|} \cdot {\|g (x,k)\|}{} \mathrm d \nu(k) \mathrm d \mu (x)  \\
\leq &\left (\int_{[n]} \int_{X}  \|f(x,k)\|^p  \mathrm d \mu (x)\mathrm d \nu(k)  \right )^{1/p} \cdot   \left (\int_{[n]} \int_{X} \|g(x,k)\|^q  \mathrm d \mu (x) \mathrm d \nu(k) \right )^{1/q}.\end{align}

In above inequality, we integrate w.r.t. $\nu$ first and then $\mu$ on the LHS. On the RHS, we do the reverse, i.e., we integrate w.r.t. $\mu$ first and then $\nu$. This gives us \begin{align}&\int_{X} \sum_{k=1}^n {\| f_k(x)\|} \cdot {\|g (x,k)\|}{} \mathrm d \mu (x)  \\
\leq &\left ( \sum_{k=1}^n \|f_k(x)\|^p \mathrm d \mu (x) \right )^{1/p} \cdot   \left ( \sum_{k=1}^n \|g_k(x)\|^q \mathrm d \mu (x) \right )^{1/q}\end{align}

This completes the proof.

Comment: You are making it too complicated. Are you interested in a simpler proof?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Of course, with the same generality, a simpler proof is always preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a  simpler proof:

Step 1: $\int_X \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \|f_k(x)\|\|g_k(x)\|d\mu(x) =\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \int_X \|f_k(x)\|\|g_k(x)\|d\mu(x)$

Step 2: $\int_X \|f_k(x)\|\|g_k(x)\|d\mu(x) \leq \|f_k\|_p\|g_k||_q$. [This is Holder's inequality].

Stpe 3: Finish the proof using the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_kb_k \leq (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|a_k|^{p})^{1/p}) (\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}|b_k|^{q})^{1/q})$

Comment: Does the inequality in step 3 have a name?

Comment: @Akira It is just a special case of Holder's inequality (w.r.t counting measure on $\{1,2...,n\}$).

Comment: It seems we can not avoid the usage of counting measure (as I did) to obtain this form which involves the finite sum.

Comment: No of course the Hölder inequality for sums does not need counting measures to be proved.

Answer (score 2):

This seems correct. You just forgot to write the integrals near the sums in the last line of the last equation. The first case $n=1$ is just the standard Hölder's inequality.

For the general case $n>1$, instead of doing a product space, you could also apply two times Hölder's inequality.
$$
\int_{X}\sum_{k}  \|f_k\| \,\|g_k\| \,\mu = \sum_{k} \int_{X} \|f_k\| \,\|g_k\| \,\mu \leq \sum_{k} \|f_k\|_p \,\|g_k\|_p
\\≤ \left(\sum_{k} \|f_k\|_p^p\right)^{1/p} \left(\sum_{k} \|g_k\|_p^p\right)^{1/p}
$$
the first identity following from Fubini theorem for positive functions.

Comment: The first equality is just linearity of the intergal. Fubini's Theorem is not involved here sinec there is integration w.r.t  a single variable.

Comment: I think I just forgot to remove the differential operators :)

Comment: Yeah, you can view that as the linearity of the integral, or as Fubini with Dirac measures ;) In particular in case of infinite sums

Comment: @Akira Then you should remove the differential operators, the "(x)" after the functions and put the $p$ as index ;)

Comment: You're right. Thank you so much!

Comment: Using Fubini's Theorem for linearity of the integral is wrong because linearity is require in the proof of Fubini's Theorem], That makes your argument circular. If we had  an infinite sum your argument would have made sense, but for finite sums it does not.

Comment: It is not wrong, just another point of view that at was in my mind at the moment. But I agree that it follows from it, but I don't see the point in putting values like good or bad over this kind of question. It is not circular, I am not wanting to prove linearity of the integral there. I don't get your problem.